# data not posting after changing the .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am making a website in PHP, everything is working fine, but when I changed the .htaccess file post form method is not posting the data.

> .htaccess file (I found this on stackoverflow.com)

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

> form

```
 <form method="post" id="form" action="view_images.php">
    <input type="text" name="img" value="images/1.jpg" id="img_name" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Do you know if the file "view_images.php" resolves? What I mean by this, try going directly to "view_images.php" in your browser. Maybe add a debug string and echo it out. My guess is that one of your RewriteRule is broken and preventing view_images.php from being loaded.

Comment: view_images.php is loading, but the variable $_POST['img'] is showing empty.

Answer (score 0):

This rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```

Is causing your POST request for `view_images.php` to be redirected to `view_images`, and thus you lose the request body (all of your POSTed data). You don't want to cause this redirect, so don't POST to the `view_images.php` URL. Remove the `.php` part so that it won't redirect:

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="view_images">
    <input type="text" name="img" value="images/1.jpg" id="img_name" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```